# Separating axis theorem in a non-orthogonal basis

Tags: algorithms, change-of-basis

Can I use the separating axis theorem in a 2D non-orthogonal basis?

Separating Axis Theorem I use: [here](http://www.dyn4j.org/2010/01/sat/)

Comment: Your problem lacks context and clarity. This can be found with a simple google search

Comment: Can you give me your google answer?

Comment: it's not directly available but it's not hard to look for it, and the edit you made just made the post quiet good